# CSS background image and backgronud-size: extending the width

Tags: css, background-image

I'm in somewhat of a situation as I need to make minor CSS adjustments but do not have permission to touch the graphics.

In this case, i have a background image (that has a width of 461px in Photoshop) and I need to extend it 4-5 pixels.

The current for CSS for this image is:

```
#screenvolumeslidermenu{
    background:url(../html_cmi/lopa/volume_bg_overlay.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    width:461px;
    height:51px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:15;
    top:678px;
    left:70px;
    display:none;
}
```

It didn't initially have the `no-repeat` property, but if I take that out and just increase the current width, the image will start to repeat. If I leave it in as is and increase the width, no visible change is made but using inspect element the width is technically increasing. See here: 
[image]

I want the right side of the black rectangle to extend a few more pixels on the right side.

I tried using `background-size` but couldn't get any decent results.

**What is the best solution here to extend the image width without touching it in Photoshop?**

Comment: Since your image has the arrow on the left which is combined with the rest of the background, there isn't a way to manipulate this with CSS. The only thing you could do if you want to avoid Photoshop is to add an adjoining background element and style it the same, but that's really hacky.

Comment: Hm, I see. So the arrow is screwing everything up, more or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation. The ideal method would be to create the whole thing using CSS. Create the main rectangle and use `:before` and `:after` to create the arrow with border styles. [Check this site out](http://cssarrowplease.com)

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-right-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-right-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-top: -36px;
}
```

Comment: I'm all for using CSS only as much as possible, and that website you linked is awesome. Giving an upvote as a great solution but unfortunately I need to use the background image.

Comment: If you're really stuck, you might want to try to add an extra element after the image element. Style it the same, give it a width of what you need and `position: absolute` it at the end of the image.

Answer (score 1):

1) background-size can accept two values, for example

```
background-size: 200% 100%;
```

should let you stretch only one dimension (can use pixels too).

2) if you don't want to touch proportions, consider creating another, narrower element that has the same background image, but aligned to the right edge, and place it over the first element, aligned to the right.  Then by moving the right piece like a slide ruler, you'll be able to vary overall width without distorting your graphics.

Comment: I will try that out and let you know how it goes. Thank you for a constructive answer.